# Is there a way to get all the relations and fields of particular model in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, graphql, laravel-models, graphql-php

I am trying to create a script that could help me generate a GraphQL schema with all fields and relations exist in the models.

if I could get that, [php-lighthouse](https://lighthouse-php.com/) would help me for the rest of the work.

Comment: this is not what I am looking for 
I am looking for a graphql generator in laravel

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get all **relations** of a particular Eloquent model without the user specifying them in some way, such as an attribute on the model that holds all relation names, or type-hinting those methods returning a relation. See [laravel-eloquent-to-graphql](https://github.com/brausepulver/laravel-eloquent-to-graphql) for an example.

You can however get all **fields** of a model (that are saved in the database) by inspecting its table.

If you're looking for a GraphQL generator, there are [Laravel Bakery](https://github.com/scrnhq/laravel-bakery) and [laravel-eloquent-to-graphql](https://github.com/brausepulver/laravel-eloquent-to-graphql). Laravel Bakery generates a GraphQL schema on-the-fly, while laravel-eloquent-to-graphql generates a GraphQL schema statically.

There is also [Lighthouse-Utils](https://github.com/deInternetJongens/Lighthouse-Utils), which can generate queries and mutations for already-defined types.